# Como aplicar funções de "If" & "Else" para BigInteger?

Tags: java

Tenho esse código em `Long` funcionando normalmente:

```
public static void main(String args[]){

  List<Long> lista = new ArrayList();  

    for(long a = 1; a <= 100; a++){

    if(a%2==0) {}
            else if (a%3==0){}
            else {
             lista.add(a);
               }   
         }
    System.out.println(lista);
   }
}
```

[image: saída certa]

Fiz esse outro código em `BigInteger` para a mesma função, mas não funciona:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<BigInteger> lista = new ArrayList();

    BigInteger começo = new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger fim = new BigInteger("100");
    BigInteger n0 = new BigInteger("0");
    BigInteger n2 = new BigInteger("2");
    BigInteger n3 = new BigInteger("3");

for (BigInteger a = começo; a.compareTo(fim) <= 0; a = a.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {

   if (a.divide(n2)==n0){}
   else if (a.divide(n3)==n0){}
   else {
       lista.add(a);
      }
    } 
  System.out.println( lista );
  }
}
```

[image: saída errada]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está apenas usando o método errado. No seu código original com `long`, você usava o `%` que é o resto da divisão. Já no seu código com `BigInteger`, você está usando [`divide`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#divide(java.math.BigInteger)), que faz divisão e não resto da divisão. Você deveria estar usando o método [`remainder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#remainder(java.math.BigInteger)) ao invés disso.

Ainda há um outro problema. Você deveria usar o `equals` ao invés do `==`. O motivo é o mesmo pelo qual não se deve comparar `String`s com `==`, ou seja, o `==` compara se dois objetos estão na mesma posição de memória, e não se têm conteúdos iguais.

Além disso, você também pode usar o método [`valueOf(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf(long)) que é bem mais prático do que o construtor que recebe uma `String`. Também é recomendado o uso das constantes [`BigInteger.ZERO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#ZERO), [`BigInteger.ONE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#ONE) e [`BigInteger.TEN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#TEN).

Por fim, não é necessário ter cláusulas `if`s e `else if`s vazias, você sempre pode reorganizar a expressão booleana correspondente.

Eis o seu código resultante:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Divisao {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<BigInteger> lista = new ArrayList<>();

        BigInteger começo = BigInteger.ONE;
        BigInteger fim = BigInteger.valueOf(100);
        BigInteger n0 = BigInteger.ZERO;
        BigInteger n2 = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
        BigInteger n3 = BigInteger.valueOf(3);

        for (BigInteger a = começo; a.compareTo(fim) <= 0; a = a.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            if (!a.remainder(n2).equals(n0) && !a.remainder(n3).equals(n0)) {
                lista.add(a);
            }
        } 
        System.out.println(lista);
    }
}
```

Eis a saída dele:

```
[1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, 31, 35, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53, 55, 59, 61, 65, 67, 71, 73, 77, 79, 83, 85, 89, 91, 95, 97]
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/lXHCIM)

Comment: Obrigado Amigo, como faço o mesmo em vez de ser BigInteger em BigDecimal?

Comment: @Rafael Quase isso. A diferença é que o `equals(Object)` pode não ser o suficiente, uma vez que no `BigDecimal`, ele considera que os valores `123.456` e `123.4560` são diferentes porque os zeros à esquerda são considerados. Neste caso você usa o `compareTo(BigDecimal)` ou o `signum()`.